Importing still images to Premiere Pro from Photoshop
I'm producing a documentary film. I'll be using Premiere Pro (for the first time).
I have tons of still images, all prepped in Photoshop (which I've been using for years).
I know Premiere can import the PSD files. But considering I only need the image, and have no need to work with the layers, I feel that's overkill.
I would like to simply import the images, without losing quality. (The resolution of the images is already larger than needed in Premiere.)
Is it safe to import PNG and JPEG files into Premiere? What are the risks? Should I just import the PSD files, assuming that guarantees the best quality image? Is there a standard practice? I'm open to other methods, as well.
Thanks for helping a newbie in video production.

PSDs work fine in Premiere. Import them as Merged layers, and they'll behave just as a JPG or PNG would. I guess there might be a slight performance hit, but I haven't noticed it.
The great thing is when you work like this, any tweaks you need to make to the PSDs while working on your video will immediately show up in Premiere, as soon as you hit save in Photoshop. It's a pretty useful feature.
